# Live Agent Post Chat Page

Tags: liveagent

I am working on a requirement to prevent the user from getting the Post Chat Survey page if they tried to initiate the chat and for some reason it did not go through.

Is there a way to determine in SFDC Live Agent that the chat initiated by the customer did not go through and based on that direct the user to a maybe different post chat page (or a post chat page without survey questions) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Information about the chat is sent via a POST to the post-chat page. The simplest solution would probably be to inspect the transcript field. If it is empty, there were no messages sent.

In Apex, that check would be `String.isEmpty($CurrentPage.parameters.transcript)`

Check out the post-chat page section of the Live Agent Developer Guide for a list of all the other fields that are passed (in the format of an example VF page that outputs the values): http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_dev/index.htm